# Unable to detect Bootstrap in website after performing check in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, widget

I am building a widget to be deployed in any site as long as they add the script tag with the src pointing to the url I set. I am trying to use javascript to detect whether or not Bootstrap library has been loaded. If it is not loaded, then I will add references to Bootstrap CDN. But, the problem is that it always return me `false`, so the code will inject new bootstrap script tag, therefore having 2 bootstrap tag at the same time which causes my modal bootstrap not working.

First of all, when my widget first loaded, it will check whether jQuery is loaded.

```
$(window).load(function()
{
    if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '1.4.2') {
        var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
        scriptTag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        scriptTag.setAttribute("src", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js");

        if (scriptTag.readyState) {
            scriptTag.onreadystatechange = function () { // For old versions of IE
                if (this.readyState === 'complete' || this.readyState === 'loaded') {
                    loadScript();
                }
            };
        } else {
            scriptTag.onload = loadScript;
        }
        // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
        (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(scriptTag);
    } else {
        // The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
        jQuery = window.jQuery;
        loadScript();
    }
});
```

This is where it checks whether bootstrap has been loaded. The `bootstrap_enabled` is always `false`.

```
function loadScript()
{
        var jsLibraries = [];

        var bootstrap3_enabled = (typeof $().emulateTransitionEnd == 'function');
        if (!bootstrap3_enabled) {
            var bootstrapCss = $("<link>",
            {
                rel: "stylesheet",
                type: "text/css",
                href: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css"
            });
            bootstrapCss.appendTo('head');

            jsLibraries.push("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js");
        }

        jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
        jsLibraries.push("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.7.2/less.min.js");
        getScripts(jsLibraries, function () {
            main();
        });
}

function getScripts(list, fn) {
    var cntr = list.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        $.getScript(list[i], function () {
            --cntr;
            if (cntr === 0) {
                fn();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what goes wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try document.load() in place of window.load()

Comment: @neophyte after using $(document).load, it just does not load at all.